# Transform and combine *.xml

Tags: xslt

I want to pull a series of relationships out of xml files and transform them into a graph I generate with dot.  I can obviously do this with a scripting language, but I was curious whether or not this was possible with xslt.  Something like:

```
xsltproc dot.xsl *.xml
```

which would produce a file like

```
diagraph {
 state -> state2
 state2 -> state3
 [More state relationships from *.xml files]
}
```

So I need to both 1) wrap the combined xml transforms with "diagraph {...}" and 2) be able to handle an arbitrary set of xml documents specified on the command line.

Is this possible? Any pointers?

Comment: Your example is not complete. What is the expexted format of the xml files, what should be produced out of them and how should the results be combined? Please, provide a complete, but the minimum possible, example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using an [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) processor and the [`collection()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection) function this is really easy**.

Below is an example using **[Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index/intro.html)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pDirName" select="'D:/Temp/xmlFilesDelete'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <wrap>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "collection(
                    concat('file:///',
                            $pDirName,
                            '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes;on-error=ignore'
                             )
                         )/*
          "/>
      </wrap>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), it processes all xml files in the file-system subtree starting at the directory, whose value is specified by the global parameter **`$pDirName`**.

**At the time this transformation was applied there were only two xml files** there:

```
<apples>3</apples>
```

and

```
<oranges>3</oranges>
```

**The correct result is produced**:

```
<wrap>
   <apples>3</apples>
   <oranges>3</oranges>
</wrap>
```

This is the simplest example possible that can be constructed. **To fully answer the question, the directory can be specified on the command line invoking Saxon. Read more about the ways to invoke Saxon from the command-line [here](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at (http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/). It uses xslt to generate dot syntax from xml documents.